# How can I reserve a name on the App Store if I want to change my existing app name?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app in the iOS app store. Let’s call it “App1”.

I am changing the app a lot and would like to call it “App2” in the new update.

I will not be submitting a brand new app, just updating the current one.

Can I create a dummy “App2” to hold the name and then switch “App1” to “App2” when ready (much like reserving a Twitter or Instagram handle?)

Comment: You can do that, but you also have to change the package name for ```App2``` when you want to release,  you'll have to rename the package name to match the ```App1``` or ```App2``` package name.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply create a new update in iTunes Connect and rename the application. The rename will only go into effect when your update is released.

Comment: Would this hold the place of the name until I am ready to release the update?

Comment: Yes. There's no need to register a new app. You just need to create an update and change the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps.

- Go to itunesconnect
- Revise your app1 from version 1.0 to 2.0
- Change app name to App2. If the name was already in use in app store you will get an error message otherwise you will hold the app name and no one will be able to use it.
- Launch your prjoect in Xcode.
- Look for plist file
- Add the following to it "Bundle display name" and its value should be "App2"
- Package / Archive and submit
- Throw a party afterwards